# Is every protein encoded by just one gene?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

Beadle and Tatum proposed the [“one gene, one enzyme” hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_gene%E2%80%93one_enzyme_hypothesis) in the 1940s, and this was later modified to “one gene, one protein”, i.e. that one gene codes for one protein.

Have any exceptions to this emerged subsequently? Are there single proteins, parts of which are encoded by separate genes?

Comment: don't forget that one gene can can code for multiple proteins... splice variants https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_splicing

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh But are there proteins that emerge from more than one gene instead of parts of one?

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh Is it possible that two adjacent genes ``melt`` together and are expressed if as they are óne gene?

Comment: The short answer to your initial question is yes. There are many examples of proteins that are the result of the expression of multiple genes. Hemoglobin, immunoglobulins, microtubules made of different tubulin subunits, etc. As for the other question, that is less prevalent in eukaryotes. It is not unheard of for bacteria to express operons as a single RNA, though ribosomes usually translate individual proteins. Viruses are known to do this. HIV's genome is translated from a long RNA that contains multiple genes into a single polypeptide which is then cleaved post-translationally.

Comment: @AMR There is a single gene that codes for a polyprotein, not multiple genes. After proteolytic cleavage multiple proteins arise. This is an example of *one gene, many proteins* and not the vice-versa.

Comment: @WYSIWYG "During viral maturation, the virally encoded protease cleaves the Pol polypeptide away from Gag and further digests it to separate the protease (p10), RT (p50), RNase H (p15), and integrase (p31) activities. These cleavages do not all occur efficiently, for example, roughly 50% of the RT protein remains linked to RNase H as a single polypeptide (p65)." http://hivinsite.ucsf.edu/InSite?page=kb-02-01-02#S2.1.2X

Comment: @AMR I didn't deny. But this essentially means that they are encoded by a single *gene*. There is no dispute there, I believe.

Comment: @WYSIWYG  you are mistaken. gag and pol are considered to be distinct and independent genes from one another. Both are genes that encode for polyprotiens. They are expressed together as they are transcribed in a single RNA, are translated as a single polypeptide chain, and then are post-translation ally cleaved by HIV proteases. Not my definition, just what virologists and geneticist shave characterized.

Comment: @AMR that's what I said. `gag` is a gene that codes for a polyprotein that gives rise to multiple proteins. That is one gene many proteins. Are you saying that `gag` and `pol` are transcribed together as a single RNA and so they should be considered one gene? That's more like a polycistronic RNA. BTW, `gag-pol` is also a gene in itself and there is a [`gag-pol` polyprotein](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P03367). I haven't yet read HIV gene expression in detail but I know it is a bit complex.

Comment: @WYSIWYG it was only addressing the question in the third comment "@VanceLAlbaugh Is it possible that two adjacent genes ``melt`` together and are expressed if as they are óne gene?" And I answered initial that you would not find it in Eukaryotes, but can see it in viruses. I am not saying they are one gene, but would fit the description of two genes being expressed as if they were one gene and then the translated product of those to genes, itself a single polypeptide chain is posttranslationally cleaved into the relevant gene products.

Comment: As this has come up again I have edited the question and provided an original reference to the idea.

Comment: You may be interested in [trans-splicing](http://www.wormbook.org/chapters/www_transsplicingoperons/transsplicingoperons.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *are* proteins encoded by more than one gene.

It would be a **heterodimer** protein of **quaternary** structure. One famous example would be haemaglobin, which is assembled from alpha and beta sub-units.

Also, one gene is capable of coding for multiple proteins!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_dimer

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_quaternary_structure

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin

Comment: Though hemoglobin is not a dimer as your answer seems to imply.

Comment: As I had modified the question I had to clarify the "yes" in your answer.

Comment: I'm surprised that one gene is capable of coding multiple genes, which brings to mind a question I'm gonna ask now.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the answer would seem to be:

> “No, a single polypeptide chain is encoded by a single mRNA from a
>   single transcript of a single gene.”

Obviously if one uses the epithet, protein, for a hetero-multimer like haemoglobin, one could say `yes` instead.

So far, nothing new since the question was posed two years ago. But, at the risk of being shot down in flames, let me suggest two possibilities.

**1. Immunoglobulins**

The vast diversity of antibodies arises not from the fact that there are a vast number of immunoglobulin genes in the genome, but that there is a repertoire corresponding to different sections of each antibodody chain, the recombination of which in individual B-cells gives rise to different genes. See, for example, [this section of Alberts *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26860/) As far as the precursor cell is concerned, the mature immunoglobulin chains are the products of different genes. As far as the mature individual B cells are concerned, each chain of their gene products arise from a single recombined gene.

You pays your money and you takes your choice.

**2. Metalloproteins**

Let us consider the metalloprotein like [urease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urease). This enzyme, which breaks down urea to ammonia and carbon dioxide, requires Nickel to function. One can adopt the standpoint that the protein is not complete without the metal cofactor. The genetics of urease has been well studied in certain pathogentic bacteria like [*Helicobacter pylori*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2417/), where it is part of a gene cluster. Other components of this gene cluster encode proteins required to deliver nickel ions to the inactive enzyme.

One could argue that without Nickel the protein is incomplete, so that functional urease is encoded by multiple genes of that cluster.

Depends what rules we are playing.

Answer (score 0):

There are protein complexes which are made up of multiple subunits.  Whether you call that one protein or a multi-protein complex might depend on whether you have a gene-centric or protein-centric point of view.

Comment: Not really. A protein is a single polypeptide chain. There are many proteins that exist (sometimes solely) as a part of multi-member complexes, but those complexes are never referred to as proteins. They're called protein complexes, even by very "protein-centric" (your phrase) biochemists.

Comment: Now, there have been cases where a complex was initially thought to be a single protein, and named as such, but further research showed it contained multiple subunits. But after the new knowledge is disseminated, one wouldn't keep referring to the complex as a protein.

Comment: @MattDMo What is meant by subunits? Doesn´t every protein contain them?

Comment: @descheleschilder - ask a question as a question post, not a comment.

Comment: @MattDMo You are kidding, right? from Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry; protein: A macromolecule composed of one or more polypeptide chains, each with a characteristic sequence of amino acids linked by polypeptide bonds. quaternary  structure: The three-dimensional structure of a multisubunit protein, particularly in the manner in which the subunits fit together. Hemoglobin is a protein... and its subunits come from distinctly different genes that encode the polypeptides that make up the subunits of the protein.

Comment: I would say the distinction is functional and structural. A polymerase holoenzyme has subunits that perform different functions and could be considered a protein complex. A nuclear pore complex is structural and provides a substrate for interactions with other proteins that creates a selective barrier into and out of the nucleus as well as creating directionality in nuclear transport. The subunits of hemoglobin or the light and heavy chains of immunoglobulins work together to produce a particular function so those would be considered more proteins than true protein complexes.